# Selenium PYTHON: write email in gmail but text goes under the signature

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, gmail

I'm writing a script to login to Gmail, open a new email and compose it.
Everything works fine. It means that I'm able to log in, to press the "Compose" button, fill in the recipient and subject boxes, and also to write the text of my message inside the main box.

The problem is that the text is being written inside my signature space instead of above it.
Example:

**main text should be here not below**
*.........

here I have a signature

signature

the main text is written here formatted as the

signature*

I tried several solutions but I cannot solve this problem. The only way is to remove my signature, but I would avoid it. Another way is to freeze the driver via `driver.implicitly_wait(5)` when Python finds the main text box, and manually click on the position where the text should start.
I locate the main box using:

`main_text = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(`
            `EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[aria-label="Message Body"]'))`
`)`
`print('main text found')`
`main_text.send_keys('text of the email')`

I would really appreciate it if someone would know how to tells Python where to write automatically.
Thank you all!

Comment: Please provide more details with DOM or url to replicate your issue

Comment: I can add part of the code. Maybe it'll be more straightforward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few hours I found a way by myself and I'll post here the solution (in case someone else will need it). I hope that answer to a mine question would not cause any problem.

When I was writing an email in Gmail via Selenium, the text was added **below the signature**, at the far bottom of the main text-box and taking the signature font. *Well, not really useful...*

The code I was using to locate the text-box object was like:

```
main_text = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[aria-label="Message Body"]'))
)                                            
                                                        
print('main text found') 
driver.implicitly_wait(3)  
main_text.send_keys('test text box')
```

or like this (copying the xpath from the blank space where the main text should go):

```
main_text = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id=":nu"]'))
)                                            
                                                        
print('main text found') 
driver.implicitly_wait(3)  
main_text.send_keys('test text box')
```

Unfortunately none of them or other location by NAME, ID, CLASS_NAME or XPATH were working properly.

**SOLUTION:**
Giving another try, I inspect precisely only the first row of the blank main text-box and I used the xpath only from that precise first line instead of the whole text-box:

```
main_text = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id=":rt"]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/p[1]'))
)                                                                                       
print('main text found') 
driver.implicitly_wait(3)  
main_text.send_keys('Test line 1\n\nTest line 2\nTest line 3\n..\nTest via Selenium chromedriver')
```

Finally, the text was written in the right position, clean above the signature.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below code, I have successfully run this code on my computer.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(20)

driver.get('https://www.gmail.com/')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[contains(@type,"email")]').send_keys("YourEmail")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[text()="Next"]/parent::button').click()

time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[contains(@type,"password")]').send_keys("YourPassword")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[text()="Next"]/parent::button').click()

# Time to load GMail fully
time.sleep(10)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(text(),"Compose")]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//textarea[contains(@name,"to")]').send_keys('To-EmailID')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[contains(@name,"subjectbox")]').send_keys('Test Mail')

# Write Email
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class,"gmail_default")]').send_keys("This is a messagebox\n")

# Send Message
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(text(),"Send") and @role="button"]').click()

print("Message Sent Successfully")
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but actually it's not working. The xpath to the login button is not working. Anyway with my code I was able to login and write the message but inside the signature field instead above it. That's it. I'd like to write it in the right space.

Comment: Not sure what happened, but the above code still working on my system just checked. Anyway, you have resolved your issue that matters.

Comment: No idea. I copied pasted your code and run it but I got errors. Chromedriver is working fine so it's not the problem here. That's interesting, though..